# Video is exported reduced in size

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, video

When I export videos they come out smaller - about 67% of the original file size (1920x1080). I set export to 100% Resolution, and I only get 67% of the image (starting from the bottom left corner - the rest is cut). The only way to export the whole image is to reduce the Resolution to 67%. I've tried various settings, but feel I must be missing something. Does anyone know why this is happening?[image: Screenshot of settings]

Comment: what you mean by "export video from Video Editing screen"?  which resolution has your original video file? and if you press F12 what is the size of the image render (press N key to show in the side panel)?  or, can you show at least a screenshot of the video editor setup, and detail which output resolution is set in Blender?

Comment: What are the dimensions of the original video? What are the render dimensions on your project? Please edit your question and add more information. Without it it's very hard to guess what your issue is or how to solve it.

Comment: I've updated some info and added a screen shot, thanks

Comment: again... what are the dimensions of your original video?  It seems to me you are dealing with video that is on HD 720 (1280x720 pixels), roughly 76% of full HD 1080...  You would need to rescale your video or change your output settings.

Comment: Have you tried following some good [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4)?

Comment: The original video is 1920 x 1080. I have tried various things, and tried looking this up all over the place, but I'm at a loss - though I'm not the most technical person

Answer (score 1):

In your Video Strip Properties make sure, **Image Offset** and **Image Crop** are unchecked.

[image: Screenshot]